# Error conflicto de plugin

Tags: wordpress-plugin

El plugin se llama Portfolio Filter Gallery Premium. El plugin genera una galería el problema es que esta generando espacios blancos y los filtros no están tomando en cuenta las categorías. Los post del portafolio se generan dentro del mismo plugin y no se necesita un custom post type externo. Al inspeccionar la consola he visto que se esta lanzando un error y no logro comprender que es lo que está causando conflicto. He probado el plugin en otro wordpress limpio y funciona correctamente. He reinstalado el plugin en el sitio donde causa el problema y sigue el mismo conflicto. Alguna idea? Gracias de antemano.
[Screenshot del problema que muestra la consola](https://share.getcloudapp.com/d5uP9Wrl)

```
jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'outerWidth' of undefined
    at s.fn.init._calcItemPositions (jquery.filterizr.js?ver=5.6:590)
    at s.fn.init._placeItems (jquery.filterizr.js?ver=5.6:772)
    at s.fn.init._handleFiltering (jquery.filterizr.js?ver=5.6:739)
    at s.fn.init.filter (jquery.filterizr.js?ver=5.6:211)
    at Object.init (jquery.filterizr.js?ver=5.6:193)
    at s.fn.init.$.fn.filterizr (jquery.filterizr.js?ver=5.6:84)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):1406)
    at e (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
```